# OO Design for attributes uncomm

Tags: java, oop

I have a class Parent which is being extended by 3 child classes, FieldOne is common in ChildOne and ChildTwo but not in ChildThree.I want to be able access FieldOne using Parent. What is the correct design?

Comment: show an example of the current solution and what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Your design is flawed, if you don't want to inherit an attribute, don't extend that class

Comment: Example: Employee class is extended by Fulltime employees , Vendors and Contractors. Vendors and contractors have isContractExpired boolean which tells if their contract has expired. I want a list of employees whose contract has expired.

Answer (score 0):

**Inheritance** is the process by which one class takes on the attributes and methods of another and it's use to express what is  called an **is-a relationship**.

Inheritance is not the correct solution to your problem if the superclass that you want to derive from has an attribute you don't need in the subclass.
You should not enforce inheritance when it is obviously not needed.